# How to prevent notifications from a skype group?

Tags: skype

I'm a member of a high-traffic skype group, which is often too much noise for me to concentrate with.

Can I prevent messages to the group from popping up as new notifications?

Comment: Not really mute since that implies the audio settings but prevent desktop notifications, correct.

Comment: Looks like there are only Options for Skype as a whole not individuals or groups.

Comment: @BradPatton - correct. Is this is so then I'll be sad :(

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a setting, although I've never used it so far (names might be off due to localization):

- Open the conversation/group you'd like to modify.
- Go to the **Conversations** menu.
- Find the **Notification Settings...**.
- Here you can modify how/if/when to open the specific group or show messages as popups.

[image: Notification Settings window (German version)]

Comment: I never have to google to find this kind of settings in Whatsapp/WeChat/etc... Microsoft has a lot to learn...

Comment: Is this still working in recent versions of Skype on Linux ? I can't find the "conversations" menu and "notification settings" for a specific group....

Comment: @Antonello Can't check right now but I'm pretty sure they removed this or more specifically never added this to the new/rewritten client.

Answer (score 28):

type /alertsoff in skype groupchat.

Comment: Make sure that there is no space before /alertsoff - otherwise, it will be handled as a message, instead as of a Skype command. (telling the whole company, on the group chat, I didn't want to hear from them was awkward... ;) )

Comment: Does not work in newer versions of Skype: "Invalid command, please try again"

Answer (score 8):

You can issue the following commands in a conversation that:

`/alertsoff` - Stops annoying popups but still keep you alive in a group
`/alertson` - Brings back popups

Much more commands in [this link](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10042/what-are-chat-commands-and-roles)

Here is a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/777122/mute-conversations-on-skype)